# Асинхронный метод

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Помогите! Почему метод onComplete выполняется синхронно, а не асинхронно?

```
findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    final Handler h = new Handler() {
                        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                        {
                            pd.setMessage("Загрузка..."+msg.what);
                            if(msg.what==20) pd.dismiss();
                        }
                    };
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                for(int i =0; i<=10; i++){
                                try
                                {
                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                                }
                                catch (InterruptedException e)
                                {}
                                h.sendEmptyMessage(i);
                                }
                                VKRequest request = VKApi.wall().get(
                                    VKParameters
                                    .from("domain", "serd_donbassa", "count", "200", "offset", "0"));
                                request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() {
                                        public void onComplete(VKResponse response)
                                        {
                                            for(int i =10; i<=20; i++){
                                                try
                                                {
                                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                                                }
                                                catch (InterruptedException e)
                                                {}
                                                h.sendEmptyMessage(i);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        });

                    pd.setMessage("Загрузка...");
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                    pd.show();
                    t.start();

                }
            });
```

Этот код обновляет только до 10, а потом зависает на 10 сек(перестает крутится ProgressDialog), а потом исчезает. Из выше сказанного следует, что метод выполняется асинхронно. Как это исправить?

Comment: а зачем такая сложность? может AsyncTask попробуете. там же легче и понятнее

Comment: @Saidolim, пробовал: метод onComplete совсем не выполняется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `executeWithListener` нужно использовать `executeSyncWithListener`

Answer (score 2):

Метод `onComplete` из `VKSDK` **всегда** выполняется в основном (UI) потоке приложения. Так уж оно сделано. Если вам в этот момент надо выполнить ещё одну асинхронную операцию, то запускайте её в новом потоке так же, как вы уже делаете или через `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Может быть это поведение может исправить вот этот метод `setUseLooperForCallListener(boolean useLooperForCallListener)` в классе VKRequest. Но он без комментов и я с ходу не совсем понял что он делает.